# React wrapper for existing library

Tags: javascript, react.js

https://github.com/BingXiong1995/react-flv-player/blob/master/lib/wrapper/ReactFlvPlayer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import flvjs from './flv.min';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class ReactFlvPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.flvPlayerRef = element => {
      this.flvPlayerRef = element;
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const {type , url, isLive, enableStashBuffer, stashInitialSize, hasAudio, hasVideo, handleError, enableWarning, enableError} = this.props;

    // 组件挂载后，拿到Ref进行操作
    if (flvjs.isSupported()) {
      const flvPlayer = flvjs.createPlayer({
        type,
        isLive,
        url,
        hasAudio,
        hasVideo
      },{
        enableStashBuffer,
        stashInitialSize
      });


      flvjs.LoggingControl.enableError = false;
      flvjs.LoggingControl.enableWarn = enableWarning;

      flvPlayer.attachMediaElement(this.myRef.current); // 将这个DOM付给第三方库
      flvPlayer.load();
      flvPlayer.play();
      flvPlayer.on('error', (err)=>{
        // console.log(err);
        handleError(err);
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { height, width, isMuted,showControls } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <video
          controls={showControls}
          muted={{isMuted}}
          ref={this.myRef}
          style={{height, width}}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactFlvPlayer.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  isLive: PropTypes.bool,
  showControls: PropTypes.bool,
  hasAudio: PropTypes.bool,
  hasVideo: PropTypes.bool,
  enableStashBuffer: PropTypes.bool,
  stashInitialSize: PropTypes.number,
  height: PropTypes.string,
  width: PropTypes.string,
  isMuted: PropTypes.bool,
  enableWarning: PropTypes.bool,
  enableError: PropTypes.bool,
  handleError: PropTypes.func
};

ReactFlvPlayer.defaultProps = {
  type: 'flv',
  isLive: true,
  hasAudio: true,
  hasVideo: true,
  showControls: true,
  enableStashBuffer: true,
  stashInitialSize: 128,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  isMuted: false,
  handleError: (err)=>{console.log(err)},
  enableWarning: false,
  enableError: false
};

export default ReactFlvPlayer;
```

Wrote some wrapper a long time ago. I am wondering if I could have done it in a better way. What are some of the improvements I could make or issues with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**flvPlayerRef?**

In the constructor, you have

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
this.flvPlayerRef = element => {
  this.flvPlayerRef = element;
};
```

This is pretty confusing. The property is either a function or an element, depending on whether it was called as a function before, and either way, it's not a ref, so it's also misnamed. It also isn't used anywhere else in the code, and consumers of the instance *already* can get a reference to the `<video>` element through the `myRef` property.

I'd remove `flvPlayerRef` completely, and also rename the less-than-informative `myRef` property name to `videoRef` or to `flvPlayerRef`.

At that point, you can make things concise by using class fields instead of a constructor:

```
class ReactFlvPlayer extends Component {
  videoRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    // ...
```

You can also consider using a functional component instead of a class-based component, as React tentatively recommends for new code - but that's not required.

**Destructured props**

This line is hard to read:

```
const {type , url, isLive, enableStashBuffer, stashInitialSize, hasAudio, hasVideo, handleError, enableWarning, enableError} = this.props;
```

When there are more than 2 or 3 properties to be destructured, I'd recommend putting each on a separate line

```
const {
  type,
  url,
  isLive,
  // ...
} = this.props;
```

But, in this case, a significant fraction of the properties are used *only* to be passed into `flvjs.createPlayer` later. Consider using rest syntax to collect those options into a single object, without having to specify each one individually:

```
const {
  enableStashBuffer,
  stashInitialSize,
  handleError,
  enableWarning,
  enableError,
  ...createPlayerOptions
} = this.props;
```

The `enableError` variable is not used. If that's deliberate, best to not extract it from the props in the first place. Or maybe you meant to assign it to `LoggingControl`? Change

```
flvjs.LoggingControl.enableError = false;
```

to

```
flvjs.LoggingControl.enableError = enableError;
```

**Nicer indentation** Rather than creating another indentation block after checking if flvjs is supported, you can consider returning early if it's *not* supported:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (!flvjs.isSupported()) {
    return;
  }
  const {
    enableStashBuffer,
    stashInitialSize,
    handleError,
    enableWarning,
    enableError,
    ...createPlayerOptions
  } = this.props;

  const flvPlayer = flvjs.createPlayer(
    createPlayerOptions,
    {
      enableStashBuffer,
      stashInitialSize
    }
  );
  // etc
```

Returning early is pretty nice, especially with more complex logic which would otherwise require multiple levels of indentation, which can get pretty hard to read.

**Spacing** There are a few places where I'd expect to see a space but don't see any given the code style in the rest of the script, or where I see spaces where there probably shouldn't be any, like `const {type , url,`, `},{`, `(err)=>{`, `const { height, width,` (do you want leading/trailing space when destructuring and with objects, or no?).

Whatever you want your code style to be, it would be good to be consistent - consider using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) to keep your style consistent, to fix things automatically, and warn you of potential bugs before they turn into runtime errors.